# Changing Img Src based on value entered in a Textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, image, textfield

I need help creating a form with the following

1. **TEXTFIELD**(will be used to enter 7digit model numbers)
2. An image placeholder (will change the image placeholder's src based on a url for example it will become src="http://yourwebsite.com/product/**TEXTFIELD**.jpg)
3. I need to somehow get the the H1 tag values from within the product's url

**#3 IS STILL UNSOLVED !**

I'm **REALLY desperate** for any type of help.
I've googled the entire day REALLY need assistance.
Thank You !

I have some code below that helps visualize what I'm kinda looking for.
Please contact me if you need clarification or if I'm a bit confusing.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
       <p>7-digit product#
         <input type="text" name="model" id="model">
       </p>
       <p>
         <input name="start" type="hidden" id="start" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/Products/">
       </p>
       <p>
         <input name="end" type="hidden" id="end" value=".jpg">
       </p>
       <p><img name="proudctimage" src="=#start#model#end" width="32" height="32" alt=""></p>
     </form>

<script>
    var model_input = document.getElementById('model');
    var start = document.getElementById('start');
    var end = document.getElementById('end');
    var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    model_input.onkeyup = function(e){
       image[0].src = start.value + model_input.value + end.value;
    }
</script>
```

---

~EDITED 9:00AM 5/29/12~

---

1. The Values entered in the textfield gets deleted if you hit enter
2. I need a way to grab a product's description stored in a H1 tag using the respective URL (The URL is the model number of what is entered in the textfield but uses a slightly different url structure that is different than the one used to grab images , see below ... http://mywebsite.com/ProductDetails.aspx?productid=**TEXTFIELD**)
   ***I Should make note that the URL used to get the H1 data will be a "cross domain" & not necessarily on the some domain. I read that jquery may not make requests on cross domains

Answer (score 3):

You could use Jquery to do this easily.

Grab a copy of Jquery from http://www.jquery.com or use the CDN version by pasting this into your head section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a simplified version:

If the start and end parts of your URL are not going to change you could simplify your form:

```
​<form>
    <label>Model Num</label>
    <input type="text" name="model" id="model" />
    <input type="button" value="Update Image" id="update" />
</form>
<img src="" />
```

​
Then With the following Jquery code, you can detect a click on the update button, grab the code from the text box and change the image src attribute to

```
http://mysite.com/products/typed_code_here
```

Just paste the jquery code (and the script tags) into your head section

```
<script>
    ​$(document).on('click','#update',function(){
        $('img').attr('src','http://mysite.com/product/'+$('#model').val()+'.jpg');
    });​​​​​​
</script>
```

If you want to do this **without Jquery** and if your html has to remain as above, you could use the following along with your original html (watch out for spelling mistakes in your code):

```
<script>
    var model_input = document.getElementById('model');
    var start = document.getElementById('start');
    var end = document.getElementById('end');
    var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    model_input.onkeyup = function(e){
       image[0].src = start.value + model_input.value + end.value;
    }
</script>
```

The onkeyup event could be changed to blur, change etc depending on how you want to update the image. I'd suggest a button such that the user can update the image when they believe the code is valid.

**Update**​

The following github project has made progress on the front of cross domain html requests with jQuery. https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

Basically you'd just need to grab the product page via ajax (jQuery.ajax()) and then in the ajax callback you'd have to scan the returned HTML for the h1 element. Ultimately cross domain ajax is a design pattern and there are best practices associated with it. Grabbing the whole HTML page for the sake of an h1 element is not very effective. Consider revising your approach and be sure to check any copyright laws/terms and conditions if the site you're referencing is not your own.

Comment: While your post is good, your code and example deviate from the OP's code.  You should try to answer the question in the same context as the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks tjscience, you're right. Not sure if you read my answer before or after my edits. I'm offering a simplification of the form based on a suggestion that the start and end values are not going to change thereby cutting down on HTML. Up to the OP's context though as you say :)

Comment: Brad I love the solution offered to fix the image grabbing portion of my request.

I need to tweak a the way the onkey behavior reacts to when a user hits enter. I'm going to assume people with ipads may hit enter assuming to move on to the next fields and then the product number previously entered just dissapears. Would you know how I could grab a product's values that are inbetween a <H1> tag based on the product's url ?

Comment: @BradBarrow Brad would you know how I can grab h1 tag info from the product's URL ? I would like to continue work based on what you have supplied. Many Thanks my friend !

Answer (score 1):

If your using jquery, you could do this:

```
$(function () {  
    $('#model').change(function () {
        $('img[name="productimage"]').attr('src', $('#start').val() + $('#model').val() + $('#end').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: If you need the update to happen as the text is entered, and not just once you've removed focus from the input, you can use `keyup()` instead of `change()`.

Comment: Yes, you could use keyup(), but you would get js errors for each incorrect image url.

Comment: You won't get javascript errors, but you will get 404 not found request errors. Of course, the best function to use depends upon your responsiveness requirements. Polling the server with each keystroke is excessive if not deemed useful.

Comment: @tjscience Thank You for taking the time to respond , I would appreciate your assistance with helping me solve #3 on my list regarding getting the data contained in the h1 tag of the product url

Answer (score 0):

In your html take a hidden `div`. suppose

```
<div id="loadSource"></div>

   $('#model').blur(function () {
        var modelVal = $.trim(this.value),
            startVal = $.trim($('#start').val()),
            endVal = $.trim($('#end').val());
        if( modelVal &&  startVal && endVal) {
           var imgUrl = startVal + modelVal + endVal,
               siteUrl = startVal + modelVal;
           $('img[name="productimage"]')
            .attr('src', );

           // process to get h1 tag

           $('#loadSource').load(''+ siteUrl +' h1', function() {
                  console.log( $('#loadSource h1').text() );
           });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to respond , I would appreciate your assistance with helping me solve #3 on my list regarding getting the data contained in the h1 tag of the product url

Comment: @user1422641 where is your `h1` tag

Comment: would this choose work as is based on the new question I posted or would create an additional field for the description from the h1 tag

Comment: @thecodeparaodx The code did not work and did not pull an image or provide data from an h1 tag via the product url and model number typed in. I copied and pasted your solution & replaced the old script. I'm assuming you wanted me to encase the code after </div> around script tags