# How to get value from form field and concatenate with url in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formfield

I am using jquery for the first time today and need help with this problem. For the all the pros out there, this issue might sound dumb but I am struggling.

I have a form field in a HTML page, and want to get value from the form field and concatenate with a url.

```
<form id="form-container" class="form-container">
        <label for="street">Street: </label><input type="text" id="street" value="">
        <label for="city">City: </label><input type="text" id="city" value="">
        <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

This is tag where I am want to add the values of street and city.

```
<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=White House, Washington DC&key=API_KEY">
</body>
```

Basically the location field in this `src` will come from the form field. so something like this:

```
<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + $('#street').val() + "," + $('#city').val()&key=API_KEY">
    </body>
```

But unfortunately this is not working and need some pointers to resolve this.

UPDATE : I am trying this method to achieve this but not working

```
$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + $('#street').val() + " " + $('#city').val() + "&key=ABC">'
```

Comment: looks like you're missing quotes

Comment: Can I add javascript variables inside html tags? Seems like I need to define it in a separate jquery files. With quotes also it is not working :/

Comment: You can, in certain places like inline click event handlers, or if you're using a templating engine or framework like angular.js, usually with special syntax. I'll try posting an answer.

Comment: I am trying by this `$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + $('#street').val() + " " +  $('#city').val()&key=` but still not working in a javascript file

Comment: Please have a look at the below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792207/changing-img-src-based-on-value-entered-in-a-textfield

Comment: @RajuChauhan What's wrong with this approach `$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + $('#street').val() + " " + $('#city').val()&key=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location={street},{city}&key=API_KEY";

$("#submit-btn").on('click', function() {
  var street = $('#street').val();
  var city = $('#city').val();
  var finalURL = url.replace('{street}', street).replace('{city}', city);
  $('.bgimg').attr('src',finalURL);
});
```

Note that you shouldn't have `src` attribute set in the `HTML`, else browser will fire a request to invalid source.

Also make sure to validate the user inputs and that you've jQuery.

Comment: @python can't tell that from the looks of it... `$body.append`.. I don't know whether `$body` is a jQuery object (if not it should be `$('body')` ... or  how you're executing this line... whether it's in an event handler etc

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the src of your image on form submit.
Possible duplicate of this thread (you will find a detailed answer there): [Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

So something like:

```
function setSrc(){
$('.bgimg').prop('src','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=' + $('#street').val() + ',' + $('#city').val() + '&key=API_KEY');
}

<form id="form-container" class="form-container" onSubmit="setSrc();">
```

Comment: Any idea what's wrong with this approach `$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + $('#street').val() + " " + $('#city').val()&key=`

Answer (score 1):

If You need to do it using jQuery then set the value of 'src' property of img tag like this:

```
$('.bgimg').prop('src', '"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=' + $('#street').val() + ',' + $('#city').val() + '&key=API_KEY')
```

Comment: Any ides what's wrong with this approach `$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + $('#street').val() + " " + $('#city').val()&key=`

Comment: I guess you are just confused how ' and " works in js `$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=' + $('#street').val() + ', ' + $('#city').val() + '&key=API_KEY');`

Comment: There was another error... you forgot to close <img> tag in the end... `$('body').append('<img class="bgimg" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=' + $('#street').val() + ', ' + $('#city').val() + '&key=API_KEY" />');` now it is working

Comment: No, in my program the tag is closed